# Execute a function while ignoring the result

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

In my JDBC template, I want to execute a PostgreSQL function for certain rows. Currently, I do:

```
JdbcTemplate t = ...;
String q = "select my_function(table.identifier) from table where ...`;
template.query(q, new Object[]{...}, result -> null);
```

Here `result -> null` is a `ResultSetExtractor` which just ignores the result set and results `null`. I am doing this because I don't really care about the result of the `my_function` function. I just want to execute it for the selected rows.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? While it works perfectly, it's kinda hackisch, in my opinion at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid that the result is sent to the client at all, use PL/pgSQL's `PERFORM` in a `DO` statement:

```
DO $$BEGIN PERFORM myfunction(...) FROM ...; END;$$;
```

You simply put `PERFORM` in the place where you would normally write `SELECT`.

I will admit that this is also kind of a hack, but at least it has a clear performance advantage.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Which `JDBCTemplate` function should then be used here? I guess `execute()` instead of `query()`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A `DO` statement has no result.

Comment: Thank you, interesting approach. I will accept later, I am going to wait for other creative ideas as well! :)